# How to make 2 functions work instead of only 1

Tags: c++

I have 2 void functions and a main func.

But since first function has while(true) it works always and due to that second is not working. How to make it work all together at the same time?

```
   void shoot()
{
    *(DWORD*)(val.gameModule + offsets.ForceAttack, 5);
    Sleep(5000);
    *(DWORD*)(val.gameModule + offsets.ForceAttack, 4);
}

void bunny()
{


    val.gameModule = (DWORD)GetModuleHandle("client_panorama.dll");

    std::cout << (GetModuleHandle("client_panorama.dll")) << std::endl;;
    val.localPlayer = *(DWORD*)(val.gameModule + offsets.lplayer);
    while (true)
    {
        if (bunnyON == 1);
        else
            return;
        val.flag = *(BYTE*)(val.localPlayer + offsets.flags);
        if (isMoving())
            if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SPACE) && val.flag & (1 << 0))
                * (DWORD*)(val.gameModule + offsets.jump) = 6;
    }
}




int main()
{


    bunny();
    shoot();
}
`
```

Comment: Short answer: Threads

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica so i have to put all my functions to a  thread?

Comment: Run each function in it's own thread.  This will require changes though since you need to make the code thread safe.

Comment: To solve this, you should use multithreading. This is an advanced C++ topic, which I suggest you learn later if you are a newbie. In this case, you need to run one of the functions in a separate thread (1 additional thread is enough since main function is already executed by "main thread").

Comment: Before you start with multi-threading, please, be aware multi-threading is not that easy. Alternatively, you could interleave your functions without threads, i.e. re-organize your code that you can perform one step per call. Then move the endless loop into `main()` and call `shoot_step()` and `bunny_step()` in the loop.

Comment: E.g. Instead of `sleep()`, you could store a start time in a "first" step and compare current time with start time in each following step to measure a duration. (`sleep()` isn't very precise btw.) ;-)

Comment: Isn't `*(DWORD*)(val.gameModule + offsets.ForceAttack, 5);` just dereferencing a `DWORD` at address `5`?

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica Looks like this entire program is a hack, writing at arbitrary memory offsets to achieve some goal. I doubt OP is concerned with thread safety, it seems impossible to me these these memory writes are synchronized so you can already throw defined behavior out the window. In principal you're right though.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux you are fully correct. Its a hack. shoot func should calculate correct address and write 5 to it,so this value will a make a shoot in game :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to do this, and check if this is what you need:

```cpp
#include <thread>

void shoot()
{
    *(DWORD*)(val.gameModule + offsets.ForceAttack, 5);
    Sleep(5000);
    *(DWORD*)(val.gameModule + offsets.ForceAttack, 4);
}

void bunny()
{
    val.gameModule = (DWORD)GetModuleHandle("client_panorama.dll");

    std::cout << (GetModuleHandle("client_panorama.dll")) << std::endl;;
    val.localPlayer = *(DWORD*)(val.gameModule + offsets.lplayer);
    while (true)
    {
        if (bunnyON == 1);
        else
            return;
        val.flag = *(BYTE*)(val.localPlayer + offsets.flags);
        if (isMoving())
            if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SPACE) && val.flag & (1 << 0))
                * (DWORD*)(val.gameModule + offsets.jump) = 6;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t1(bunny);
    std::thread t2(shoot);

    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    return 0;
}
```